# Restrict OpenERP rules for employees

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

Can I add a record rule that restrict write access for employees so he can modify only his information?
I test this but it is not working:

In Access Control list I add the write access to the Employee object.

```
*/Add a new rule to the Employee object RULE1 :[('user_id', '=', user.id)]  --read and write checked
*/Add a new rule RULE2 to the Employee object:[('user_id', '!=', user.id)] --read is checked
```

Answer (score 0):

**[('id','=',user.id)]** and **select READ, WRITE** operation then login user can see only his record.

You need to add this rule for hr.employee model.